# es6 TS module imports an AMD-like module: can we avoid the error TS2306 File "..." is not a module?

Tags: typescript

I have file `A.js` (non-TypeScript) that looks like this:

```
module({
}, function (imports) {
    return {
        foo: function () {
            // ...
        }
    };
});
```

which is in a module format similar to AMD, and the implementation is similar to requirejs, just a slightly different format.

Then file `B.ts` (TypeScript) imports it:

```
import A from '../old-code/A'
console.log(A)
```

This gives an error like

```
ERROR in ./src/app.ts
(9,17): error TS2306: File '/path/to/B.js' is not a module.
```

Is there some way to fix this, so that TypeScript can know how to import it?

I'm new to TypeScript... I have a feeling there's a way to make a type definition for it or something?

EDIT: I read about [declaration files](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/by-example.html) but that doesn't say anything about how to work with importing a file that is not TypeScript.

I hope there's a way to define what the file imports and exports. If not, that would be sweet to add.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> which is in a module format similar to AMD, and the implementation is similar to requirejs, just a slightly different format.

To my best knowledge, importing non-standard modules in TypeScript requires modifying compiler, which is quite impossible for end-users.

However you can still make a concession by `declare function require(mod: string): any` or something similar in your module system.

Then you can write `require('A')` to import your module at runtime. The cost is no type checking in compile time.

---

In case you are not using `allowJS` flag. You can also write a declaration file like:

A.d.ts

```
declare var a: {
    test: number
}
export = a
```

Note the naming convention, if you have code `A.js`, a companion `A.d.ts` will be automatically searched by compiler for `import * as A from './A'`

Comment: Where do I put that? Do I put it inside `A.d.ts` alongside `A.js`?

Comment: For `declare reuiqre`, put it in a global `typing.d.ts` where compiler will search. I also updated approach using `A.d.ts`. Please check it.

Comment: I am indeed using `allowJs`, and am getting that error with that file. Guess I have some learning to do! Basically, `A.js` exports an `Object` with the property `foo` which is ` Function` with no args and no return value. What might the d.ts. file look like?

Comment: I'm afraid you cannot. Because `allowJs` instructs compiler to find JavaScript source rather than your definition file. So `declare require` approach is the preferable way.

Comment: I have `allowJs` set to true, but the file `A.js` is outside the `includes` location, and I'm using `paths` to define where non-ts files are located. I just got it working too, woot woot! My `A.d.ts` file looks like `export function foo(): void`, and i `B.ts` I do `import {foo} from 'external/path/A'` (to import from `external/path/A.js`). It's compiling and Webpack is working (I'm using ts-loader). Sweeeeeet!